# Encoding data to handle corruption

Tags: algorithm, disk, corruption

I've got some data that needs to be stored on disks (hard drives).  I'm seeing corruption, usually one or two sectors (512bytes) when writing to a USB disk.

The data is stored in files, the files tend to be one or two MB in size

I'd like to encode the data such that I can recover from some errors - not the usual bit flip errors, in my case I tend to be missing larger chunks

I'm hoping to explore some options, anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to research [Reed–Solomon error correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_error_correction) used by CDs, DVDs and Blu-ray discs. It can correct for much longer sequences of errors than bit flip correction used in ECC memory. Honestly though, I'd just buy more reliable disks or write each file twice.

Answer (score 1):

I'd wonder if something is not getting written to disk at the correct time - e.g. by the time you turn the power off.

If you want to do this with coding theory, I'd start by looking at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erasure_code.

If you start with an ordinary code, you almost certainly want to interleave the code - if you think of the sectors as rows, you want to write your data in columns, so that losing one whole sector = row, loses you only 1 byte (or 1 bit) in every N, where you have N-way interleaving - each column is N rows deep.

If it's dodgy hardware - perhaps the underlying flash has had stuff overwritten too many times (does your USB drive do http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_levelling?) it might make sense to put a checksum in each sector so you know which ones are broken. If you are failing to write stuff at all, you'll need to do something trickier e.g. checksum some file metadata as well as the sector itself, to make sure that sectors that should have been overwritten but aren't don't look like they are valid because the previous contents also had a valid checksum.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the proper things to do are

- verify that the code that writes the data properly checks for error codes and return values coming from the write routine. if it is your own code it might be that you don't check that the data actually made it to the disk in its entirety
- if it's not a problem in your code, your hardware is broken and needs to be fixed